# How to add images on top of each other in for loop?

Tags: python, opencv, addition

I've got 4 images. I want to get 1 image which is an overlay of all 4 images.
My code doesn't do this correctly. Here is my code so far:

```py
framefiles = [file for file in os.listdir(inputvideopath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(inputvideopath, file)) and file.endswith('jpg')]
for frame_id, frame in enumerate(framefiles):
    if frame_id < 1:
        img1 = cv2.imread(output_dir + frame)
    if frame_id >= 1:
        img2 = cv2.imread(output_dir + frame)
        final_img = cv2.add(img1,img2)
        cv2.imshow('hh',final_img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Overlaid how? See [`cv2.addWeighted`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gafafb2513349db3bcff51f54ee5592a19).

Comment: Just all images on top of each other to get 1 final image. I don't need to add specific weights to each image. I just need to create a forloop which does the trick. Because in the future I will have more than 4 images to make an overlay-image

Comment: If you place 4 images with the same size on top of each other you will just see the last image. Do you want to add transparency or are the images of different sizes and how should they be positioned? Be more precise and offer some images please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71981723/overlapping-a-series-of-images-on-a-single-image-using-python can this be done? please help

Answer (score 4):

You better DON'T use loops, if you don't want to handle exact weights. With each iteration you'd give the newly overlayed image proportionately too much weight w.r.t. to the already merged image.

Let's see these four images:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

I prepared some code to visualize:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

images = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.jpg', '4.jpg']
images = [cv2.resize(cv2.imread(i), (400, 400)) for i in images]

# Don't do loops, m'kay?
output = images[0]
for i, image in enumerate(images[1:]):
    output = cv2.addWeighted(output, 0.5, image, 0.5, 0)
    cv2.imwrite(str(i) + '.png', output)

# Do linear blending using all images at once.
output = (np.array(images) / len(images)).sum(axis=0).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('output.png', output)
```

The (intermediate) output(s) of the loop look like that:

[image: i1]

[image: i2]

[image: i3]

The night image is most prominent, whereas Paddington can be hardly seen.

It'd be better to divide all images by the number of images you want to overlay, and then sum them. Using NumPy, that's the given one-liner, and that'd be the output:

[image: output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
NumPy:         1.19.5
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Nice selection of example images! ;)